# Updating from 1.6.8 to 2.7.2

Tags: updating, 2.7.1, backup, 1.x

Does anyone have any experience updating EE with this big of a jump between versions?  I need to update a huge website to 2.7.2 so that I can upgrade to PHP 5.3 on the hosting server.  Being that it's such a big site and I don't really have any EE experience, I'm a bit gun shy.  I've read and re-read the instructions for making a version update, and they do seem pretty straightforward.  There aren't any add-ons that I need to worry about at least.  Would trying this out on a local server first be an unnecessary hassle?  Should I just make all my back ups and go for it?

Comment: You'll absolutely want to do this on a local dev server. How rocky and involved the upgrade path depends a great deal on how the EE1 site was built and what add-ons are at play. Take a look at Paulo's answer on [EE 1 to EE2 Upgrade](http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/a/1324/22). It's got all of the bases covered.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the above, my method goes like this:

1. Copy the site and database to a development environment, you can use your own computer running MAMP/WAMP, use a subdomain on the existing hosting account, or even an unused hosting account
2. Take a backup of site and database, you can usually do this via the hosting control panel
3. Upgrade EE1 addons/extensions/plugins to latest available
4. Upgrade EE to 1.7.1 and check it all works as expected
5. Take another backup
6. Download latest EE2, and all the addons you need to replace via Devot-ee.com, extract files ready to upload
7. Rename your /system /themes folders to /systemOLD and /themesOLD
8. Upload the EE2 /system and /themes folders, and also the /images folder
9. Upload addon files as per their instructions
10. Run the EE2 installer and follow the on screen instructions
11. When the installer is done login to the control panel and install addons
12. Check your new EE2 site out, depending what you had on the old site you may need to adjust some template tags or tweak to get working again - often some addons require template tweaks.

Comment: i skipped step 3 and 4 and make the 1.6.8 site just work on dev (why update twice, e.g. to 1.7 first?). Also set default language to english for easy update. Convert nGen-file fields and other 2.x incompatible fields to TEXT or TEXTAREA. After that check extensions and modules that you can disable. When the 1.6.8 site works in your dev-environment, continue with step 5 and the update (straight from version 1.6.8)

Comment: I've consulted the solutions above, but it seems like I've had to work with making the jump directly from 1.6.8 to 2.7.2. I did this on my local server.  Worked pretty well but I lucked out since I don't have any add-ons to upgrade.  However, not everything is showing up on my home page and the other pages have absolute paths to domain links.  So, I'm guessing there are elements on my homepage with links or srcs to the remote server and that's why it looks funny.  Can I change the {site_url} in the database or admin somewhere to check this?

Comment: i use reelocate to set the path and url in the many places. after upload use it again. reelocate is a tiny bit smart and will fill in the current path it finds.

Answer (score 0):

First you should update to EE 1.7.1 which would be updated to 2.7.2 without any problem.