# Upgrading Solspace add-ons from EE1 to EE2

Tags: solspace, ee1, upgrade

We have an EE 1.7.3 site with these Solspace add-ons:

- Static Page Caching
- Freeform
- Rating
- User
- Friends

Is there a preferred way to upgrade these items? Based on this post ([EE1 to EE2 Upgrade](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/1322/ee1-to-ee2-upgrade)), I'm understanding that I need to upgrade EE first, then upgrade the add-ons.

Backups we have covered and we're running trial upgrades on a dev server first, until we get it right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, I would strongly suggest to **upgrade add-ons first, then EE**. This isn't only for Solspace add-ons, but any add-on for EE. Make sure you **update your add-ons to the latest version available for EE1 first**, then upgrade to EE2. Sometimes, you need to then upgrade the add-ons to the latest version available for EE2.

This usually gives you the smoothest upgrade path to having your add-ons working correctly on EE2. Moving to EE2 while still using an add-on version that was EE1-only (at the time of the add-on's version) can be a painful experience.

Of course, also **make sure you make backups at every step**, in case you need to backtrack to a previous state. Reading the upgrade instructions for each add-on, just in case there's a special requirement, is also highly recommended.

Comment: Very good suggestion. Sadly, some other third-party add-ons have no EE2 equivalent, so we'll be looking for some alternatives. In the case of SolSpace, I believe you have us covered.

Comment: Yes, the Solspace add-ons you mentioned above indeed have EE2 versions.

Comment: Our big move is to get our Gallery from EE1 into Assets using Solspace Gallery to Assets Importer Bundle. Almost 4000 photos from over 200 users.

Comment: Following up: We just did our first trial run of our upgrade and it went very well. Many thanks for the help on this.