# EE1 to EE2 update - cannot delete a nGen file field

Tags: matrix, update

Upgraded this EE1 site to EE2 (not without issues but managed to get most of them fixed followed this [Upgrading an EE1 site to EE2 with nGen File field](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/1/upgrading-an-ee1-site-to-ee2-with-ngen-file-field) as a guide but forgot 1 field). 
I'm stuck with 1 issue regarding 1 ngen file field that I forgot to convert to a text field.

This ngen file field sits inside a matrix field in just 1 entry in 1 channel.

I'm simply trying to delete this channel and its channel field group and recreate it without the ngen file field but I keep getting an error when I try to **access** the field:

```
    An Error Was Encountered 
Unable to load requested field type file: ft.ngen_file_field.php. 
Confirm the fieldtype file is located in the expressionengine/third_party/ directory
```

When I try to **delete** the field the error is:

```
A Database Error Occurred Error Number: 1091

Can't DROP 'col_id_15'; check that column/key exists

ALTER TABLE exp_matrix_data DROP col_id_15

Filename: third_party/matrix/ft.matrix.php

Line Number: 1544
```

Any suggestions on how to tackle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That SQL code

```
UPDATE exp_channel_data
SET field_id_XX = CONCAT('{filedir_YY}', field_id_XX)
WHERE field_id_XX != ''
AND field_id_XX NOT LIKE '{filedir_%'
```

should work but there may be instances also where you need to manually go into the exp_ff_fieldtypes table and change the nGen instance to 'file' and the same thing for exp_channel_fields

Comment: was unable to get anywhere with the sql statement, but by manually changing the offending matrix fieldtype to text I was able to access it in the control panel and delete the field group and channel. Like I said it was just 1 entry in that 1 channel - starting from scratch isn't a big deal. Thanks Steven!

Answer (score 2):

I had exactly the same issue you had except I hadn't converted any of my fields first, I just totally spaced them. It is a little hard to be sure what you have and haven't tried, especially browsing from my phone, but I believe the [SQL query here](http://ellislab.com/forums/viewreply/784231/) did the trick for me. Pasting it here for your convenience:

```
UPDATE exp_channel_data
SET field_id_XX = CONCAT('{filedir_YY}', field_id_XX)
WHERE field_id_XX != ''
AND field_id_XX NOT LIKE '{filedir_%'
```

**Make sure you backup your database before you do anything like this!**